# Unable to add GitHub link or username to profile

Tags: bug, profile-page

When logged into stackoverflow.com on the users/edit page when I place my GitHub  username or URL in the the "GitHub link or username" field and click the "Save changes just for this community" or the "Save and copy changes to all public communities" button I am presented with this error:

[image]

Comment: So, did you click the link in the error message?

Comment: Do you perhaps have a password manager that auto-fills the email field? That could cause you unintentionally trying to change the email address associated with your account.

Comment: @Cerbrus Yes, that takes me to a link to reset my password. But, I'm already logged in and able to post, additionally I know my password, it's saved in lastpass.

Comment: @Stijn I do not have a password manager installed on this browser.

Comment: @Anthony: did you try resetting the password for the account you're trying to link?

Comment: Just checked, works for me. But there isn't even an email address field present on the page, so it's very odd that you get this error.

Comment: I tried logging out and back in. I still get the same error. I will try resetting my password. I'm not sure why I would need to do that though.

Comment: @Cerbrus after resetting my password I still get the same error.

Comment: @Anthony: But now you should have 2 different accounts (logins). You can merge them somewhere in your profile.

Comment: @Cerbrus I'm not sure what you mean. On the my logins page, for me, https://stackoverflow.com/users/mylogins/2800469 I have just one login for Stack Exchange.

Comment: Looking at the POST request sent when I press that button, I do not even see an email address.

Comment: We probably won't be able to help you. Your best bet will be to contact the support team directly via https://stackoverflow.com/contact

Comment: Is it possible another account is using the github link?

Comment: It sounds like you accidentally created a separate account with your Github email

Comment: This was resolved by support. I received an email from them stating they merged my accounts. I don't really know what that means, as far as I know I had/have one stack exchange account. After I received the email I was able to add my github username to my profile.

Comment: @Anthony I suggest adding that as an answer and accepting it.